# Why can't I find the random() function in cppreference but can in Linux man page?

Tags: c

https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=random&button=

There is only `rand` in the C search result, while there is `random()` in `man 3 random` Linux man page.

As far as I know, `3` in `random(3)` means it's a library function. Also you can tell this from the manpage:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdlib.h>  //from the standard library

       long int random(void);
```

So why there is no this `random` function in cppreference?

Comment: The fact that's it's a C library doesn't mean it's standard C. My man page has a "conforming" section. Compare that of `rand` and `random`.

Comment: `rand` is conforming to SVr4, 4.3BSD, **C89**, **C99** and  POSIX.1-2001. `random` is conforming to 4.3BSD and POSIX.1-2001. As far as I know cppreference.com only covers the **C*** standards.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you both. I compared `rand` and `random` and got the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't I find the random() function in cppreference but can in Linux man page?
>
> why there is no this random function in cppreference?

Because cppreference documents the C standard and not extensions and `random()` is a linux (BSD, then POSIX) extension to C standard.

Be sure to read `future_test_macros(7)` and `standards(7)`. Note the [random(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) parts:

```
Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

   random(), srandom(), initstate(), setstate():
       _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
           || /* Glibc since 2.19: */ _DEFAULT_SOURCE
           || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE
```

and:

```
CONFORMING TO

       POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, 4.3BSD.
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw, on my machine the **Conforming** part is written in this order: `CONFORMING TO POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, 4.3BSD.`, so does https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html. linux.die.net may be a little bit old I think. Does the order (`POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, 4.3BSD.`) matter or mean something?

Comment: Nee, the `linux.die.net` site is an _archive_ of man pages. I was lazy enough that I didn't bother finding it on `man7.org` page. No, the order is irrelevant, the terms are explained in standards(7).

Comment: OK got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**`randomize()` and `random()` are not part of the standard C library**.  The function `random()` and `srandom()` are part of `POSIX` and not available on `Windows`. `rand()` and `srand()` are part of the standard C library and will be provided by any standard-conforming implementation of C.

This is the cause because you can't find the page of cppreference for `random()` function. **It is a POSIX only function.**

Comment: Well ... strictly speaking, on POSIX systems, `random()` is part of the standard C library (`libc.so`). You don't need to link to a "POSIX library" or something to use it.